# Any need for SharePoint 2010 workflows in SharePoint 2013/2016?

Tags: workflow

I am working on replicating some apps from SharePoint 2013 in a stand-alone instantiation, where SharePoint 2013 workflows were disabled, to O365/SPoL where it's up to me to use whatever workflow manager I want. Hooray!

But, I have to maintain the old instantion, too. Long story, but hey, the paychecks keep coming.

So, considering that I have to do all this manually anyway, is there any reason to make SP 2010 workflows going forward? Sounds like a no-brainer; but, I'm late to the 2016 game.

Actual question: **Are there any kinds of workflows that SHOULD be created as 2010 workflows?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there any kinds of workflows that SHOULD be created as 2010 workflows?

SharePoint Foundation 2013 farms cannot use 2013 workflows, only 2010 workflows. (2016 does not have a Foundation version.)

Some things are just simpler in 2010 workflows. For example, there's a “Lookup Manager of a User” action.

Some of the features in SP2010 workflows are missing in 2013 workflows. But, in general, they can be duplicated using 2013 workflow REST API calls.

The security model is simpler in 2010 workflows, if used correctly. (The Impersonation steps.)

2010 workflows run on the web front end servers while 2013 workflows can be (and are recommended to be) run on a separate application server. Which runs quicker, 2010 or 2013, depends on how the farm is configured.

Answer (score 1):

I would encourage a use of SharePoint 2010 workflows in conjunction with Microsoft Flow (where possible). Flow can be used via the On-Premises Data Gateway. I would discourage SharePoint 2013 workflows as they're using a deprecated product.

Comment: Trevor, Which deprecated product? SharePoint Designer or 2013 workflows?

Comment: 2013 workflows. Specifically, Workflow Manager.